# How to deep link to OpenTable

Tags: ios, deep-linking

I'm trying to add a deep link to OpenTable in my iOS app and I can't find the url scheme anywhere. Does OpenTable support deep links and if so where can I find the url scheme?

Thanks

Comment: have you find any answer related to your question?

Comment: No I never found anything, but that was a year ago so there may be new information now

Answer (score 0):

There's a reference for app URL schemes online that does list OpenTable. I can't speak to whether the information is accurate, but take a look: <del>http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#OpenTable</del>

Edit:  That site is gone, so here's an archived version of the page:
https://web.archive.org/web/20160505224800/http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes

Comment: That link is broken

Comment: Yes, that site looks like it's gone now. I added a link to an archived version of it.